# What conditions are required for transformations of limits to be valid?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, transformation

Consider a continuous single variable real valued function $f(t)$ defined on some non empty finite interval $D$.

Say we wish to find the limit of $f(t)$ as $t$ approach some point $t_{d}  \in D$ (here lets impose from above)

$$L = \lim_{t\rightarrow t_{d}^{+}} f(t) $$

Often we can apply a transformation on the limit to evaluate i.e. (log, exponential, trigonometric)-transforms. We then evaluate the transformed limit and finally then take the inverse transform to solve. For instance consider the following:

$$L = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}}  t^t$$

As $t^t$ is continuous for $t > 0$ we can apply the log-transformation

$$\ln(L) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}}  \ln\left(t^t\right) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}}  t\ln\left(t\right) = 0$$

We then take the inverse log-transformation to find $L$

$$ L = e^{0} = 1 $$

My question is, under what conditions must we meet to use a given transform? Under what circumstances could I use say a Fourier transform?

Comment: It's continuity again. Continuous functions preserve limits. So here you need to know that log and exp are continuous, which is true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Is continuity the only component of the function over the defined interval all that is required? Would about it being strictly increasing/decreasing?

Comment: Continuity is all you need, more or less by definition. Monotonicity is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your comment. If OK with you, could you please type up as an answer and I will set it as such. If there is a theorem that you have invoked here, could you please add to the answer. Again, thanks for your comment.

Comment: f($t_d$) is defined because $t_d$ is in D and f is defined over D.

Comment: @WilliamElliot - yes indeed. I will edit my post. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to fall in the following general category:

You have a function $f(t)$ whose limit as $t$ tends to some $t_0 $ you cannot evaluate. However, you've also got some ***continuous bijection*** $g(t)$ such that you know the limit of $g(f(t))$ as $t$ tends to $t_0$. Then you can recover the initial limit $\lim_{t \to t_0}f(t) = \lim_{t \to t_0}g^{-1}(g(f(t))) = g^{-1}(\lim_{t \to t_0}g(f(t))) $, where the second equality follows by continuity of g.

In your example, $f(t)=t^t$ and $g(t)=\log t$ and $g^{-1}(t)=e^t$

So I guess you need continuity and bijectivity assumptions. Regarding your idea about using Fourier transforms, it is a little bit unclear to me what you have in mind, because a Fourier transform is a transformation of functions, a map from a space of functions to a space of functions, so I don't think it can be generally applied to problems with limits.